# Help creating a rational function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

Create a rational function with vertical asymptotes $x=\pm1$ and oblique asymptote of $y=2x-3$ and a $y$-intercept of $4$.

Comment: I'd start by sketching out what I know.  Draw the asymptotes and intercepts.

Comment: Since you're new here, I'd like to mention that it would help if you show what you have already tried. This helps us know where you got stuck, and allows us to better answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can go by parts, a la Jack.

First, you want your function to have vertical asymptotes at $x=1,-1$. So we really want  $$\tag 1 \frac{1}{(1-x)(1+x)}$$

Now, as $x\to\infty$; this has a "oblique" asymptote of $0$, so we can just add the asymptote we want: $$\frac{1}{(1-x)(1+x)}+2x-3$$

Now, let's evaluate this at $x=0$. It gives $$1-3=-2$$. Since $(1)$ evaluates to $1$; we can multply it by the constant that will give us $4$, i.e. $7$. Then  $$\frac{7}{(1-x)(1+x)}+2x-3$$

will evaluate to $4$ on the origin, and have the required conditions. You can try and produce more examples to get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

For one family of rational functions $f(x)$ having vertical asymptotes **only** at $x=\pm 1$, consider those that can be written in the form $$f(x)=p_1(x)+\frac{p_2(x)}{(x+1)^m}+\frac{p_3(x)}{(x-1)^n}$$ for some positive integers $m,n,$ and some polynomials $p_1,p_2,p_3$, with $p_2,p_3$ in particular being non-$0$ polynomials of respective degrees $<m,$ $<n$. Such a function has a slant asymptote if and only if $p_1(x)$ is the line toward which the function tends asymptotically.

Hence, any rational functions $f(x)$ in our family having $y=2x-3$ for a slant asymptotes can be written in the form $$f(x)=2x-3+\frac{p_2(x)}{(x+1)^m}+\frac{p_3(x)}{(x-1)^n},$$ with $m,n,p_2,p_3$ as described above.

We're just looking for *one* such example, so to make it simpler on ourselves, we may as well assume $m=n=1$, so that $p_2,p_3$ must be constant polynomials, and our function will be $$f(x)=2x-3+\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{B}{x-1}$$ for some non-zero constants $A,B$. All that remains is to choose non-zero constants $A,B$ so that $f(0)=4$ (*i.e.*: $f(x)$ has $y$-intercept $4$).